# Rails - Capybara - reset_sessions isnt working with Google OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, rspec, capybara

My app requires users to login via Google OAuth. When I run multiple tests Google OAuth is not resetting the session, so after the first test all following tests access our site and are already logged in.

I discovered this issue fairly recently and have run into 3 scenarios (I've included basic examples). Each scenario starts by having the user navigate to our login page, click a button that sends user to Google OAuth, logs in and then verifies the url.

The **first scenario** is just navigating to our site and logging in. The result of this is that the first test passes, but all following tests are expecting to arrive at the Google OAuth login page but are already logged in:

```
feature 'All Films Page' do
  context 'user is logged in as an Admin role' do
    before(:each) do
        Capybara.reset_sessions!

        visit('/')
      app.google_signin.sign_into_app('admin')
    end

    scenario '1' do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end

    scenario '2' do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end
  end
end
```

The **second scenario** adds a 'reset_sessions!' for Google OAuth. The result of this is that after the first test, the user arrives at Google OAuth but the previous user is a selectable option as previously logged in.

```
feature 'All Films Page' do
  context 'user is logged in as an Admin role' do
    before(:each) do
      visit('https://accounts.google.com')
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      visit('/')

      app.google_signin.sign_into_app('admin')
    end

    scenario '1', :integration do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end

    scenario '2', :integration do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end
  end
end
```

The **third scenario** adds two 'reset_sessions!' for Google OAuth. This creates the intended result of each test having its session reset.

```
feature 'All Films Page' do
  context 'user is logged in as an Admin role' do
    before(:each) do
      visit('https://accounts.google.com')
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      visit('/')

      visit('https://accounts.google.com')
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      visit('/')

      app.google_signin.sign_into_app('admin')
    end

    scenario '1', :integration do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end

    scenario '2', :integration do
      expect(page).to have_current_path('/films')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing you should mock or stub external behaviour. Let's think of a billing service where you need to test behaviour of a credit card payment... You don't want to pay real money when you run your tests. There are also approaches where people mock Database behaviour completely and are only testing with unit tests because they are faster and they say the DB layer is not what they want to test, it's their own application.
For your example, which is an integration test you should have a look at examples where people stub the external call to an oauth provider with rspec. Why? Because you want to test your apps internal behaviour and not the behaviour of google... You are using a special version of google oauth and therefore you can see it as a contract between your app and the external provider. One page which explains what I'm talking about is http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/10/16/how-to-test-drive-omniauth-google-oauth2-for-your-rails-app

Answer (score 0):

This is because Capybara can only clear cookies for the domain it is on - so you need to clear the cookies on every domain where them being saved would affect your test. Assuming you are using the `selenium` driver since you don't mention otherwise that should be possible by visiting each domain and doing

```
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

rather than needing to call `reset_session!` multiple times.  That being said, is there a good reason you actually need to really log in with Google rather than putting whatever authentication library you're using into test mode?  For instance with `omniauth` - https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: Hi Thomas, one question I had for omniauth: If testing against a staging environment (and a url), would I need access to the staging db in order to use omniauth? (When testing locally I have access to my test db)

Comment: @Justin if you're testing against a staging environment (the app is not being run/managed by Capybara) then you can't use the `omniauth` test mode and would need to either log in via real google (along with clearing the cookies from multiple domains), or you'd need to use a programmable proxy like `puffing-billy` to mock the responses from google.